# Play YouTube Video from a YouTube URL with in the app in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying play a YouTube Video from a YouTube URL with in the app in iOS 6.0
Belo is my code. It is not able to play video. Please suggest.

```
- (void) playYouTubeVideoWithUrl:(NSString*) youTubeUrl andFrame:(CGRect)aFrame
{
    UIWebView *youTubeWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame] autorelease];
    [youTubeWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [youTubeWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [youTubeWebView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [youTubeWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    youTubeWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:youTubeWebView];


    NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html>\
                           <head>\
                           <style type=\"text/css\">\
                           iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
                           body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                           </style>\
                           </head>\
                           <body>\
                           <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                           </body>\
                           </html>", youTubeUrl];

    [youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: maybe there is smthng wrong with your video URL

Comment: can u post youTubeUrl you tried ?

Comment: Here is the url youTubeUrl  = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XccYAtozrec

Comment: I got the solution, i had to make it embed like..

NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@", videoId];